# java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass

Tags: java, android

my application starts well, but it has a certain function that is causing the crash and closing the app, this is the Android Studio logcat.

Please see the below message for more details.I am not sure how to resolve this error.Please help me to resolve this.

--------- beginning of crash

```
2020-08-06 10:45:44.457 1313-1313/com.firelove.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.firelove.app, PID: 1313
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #34: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.angopapo.datooapp.modules.centersheet.CenterSheetBehavior
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass com.angopapo.datooapp.modules.centersheet.CenterSheetBehavior
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.K(CoordinatorLayout.java:649)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout$f.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:2896)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.i(CoordinatorLayout.java:1740)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.generateLayoutParams(CoordinatorLayout.java:112)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:904)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:554)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:461)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:383)
        at android.view.View.inflate(View.java:26192)
        at d.b.a.f.b.a.g(CenterSheetDialog.java:82)
        at d.b.a.f.b.a.setContentView(CenterSheetDialog.java:61)
        at d.b.a.d.b0.w(QuickActions.java:92)
        at com.firelove.app.home.profile.i1.q(MyProfileFragment.java:193)
        at com.firelove.app.home.profile.q0.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7341)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7307)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27796)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7156)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:494)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:975)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's written in your log:

Check XML file line #34 (i'm guessing it's in `CenterSheetDialog.java` or `MyProfileFragment.java` layout file)

Comment: Not much I can do for you without you providing.some of your code